# Setting video src as blob from getUserMedia in Safari not working

Tags: javascript, safari, blob, getusermedia, web-mediarecorder

I'm trying to allow users to record a video of themselves, and then show a preview of the video. The problem seems to be, that setting the src of the preview video element to the blob doesn't work in Safari like it does in Chrome and Firefox.

Is this possible at all, or is there maybe another way I could go about doing this without uploading the video to the server first?

Here's how I'm setting the src attribute, which like I said works in Firefox and Chrome:

```
let blob = new Blob(this.chunks, { type: 'video/webm' });
this.videoPlaceholder.src = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

I tried to create a source element in the video tag with the blob as the src attribute, calling .load() on the video element, and a couple other solutions, but nothing seems to be working.

Comment: Safari doesn't produce webm files but mp4 ones.

Comment: I didn't see any mention about that when looking it up, but yes, setting it from video/webm to video/mp4 seemed to do the trick. Works in Firefox and Chrome as well. Thanks!